# How should I import Bootstrap with Rails 6 and Webpack?

Tags: webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I switched my `application.css` to SCSS by renaming it to `application.scss`, then I installed bootstrap by running:

```
yarn add bootstrap
```

and to import Boostrap's scss, I added:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

to the top of my `application.scss` but I'm getting this error:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-04-26 10:56:23 +0100
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering home/index.html.haml within layouts/application
  Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 17)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 3752)



ActionView::Template::Error (Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss.
        on line 1:1 of app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
>> @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";

   ^
):
     6:     %title Project X
     7:     = csrf_meta_tags
     8:     = csp_meta_tag
     9:     = stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track": "reload"
    10:     = javascript_pack_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track": "reload"
    11:   %body
    12:     =link_to "Project X", root_url

app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:1
app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:9
```

I also tried:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

and:

```
@import "~bootstrap";
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that on Rails 6.0.2.2, by default, WebPack is used for handling JavaScript but the asset pipeline for handling stylesheets.

I moved to using WebPack for everything by placing my stylesheets in `javascript/src/application.scss` and using

```
= stylesheet_pack_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track": "reload"
```

and

```
import "../src/application.scss"
```

following the instructions in Rails WebPacker's documentation: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/tree/v5.1.1#usage

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in my project but fixed it running the command below :

**yarn add bootstrap jquery @popperjs/core**